# JBoss / Resteasy how to prepopulate objects using a filter before the exposed API?

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy

Environment: JBoss AS 7, RestEasy 3.0.5.

I would like to use a preprocess filter in my application to authenticate a particular user and add this authenticated user to the **request scope**. I tried the following:

```
@Provider
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // authenticate, lookup user code etc...
        requestContext.setProperty("User", new User("test"));
    }
}
```

And then access it at the bean level using:

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean {

    @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello " + servletRequest.getAttribute("User");
    }

}
```

However the Context elements are not injected when the bean is annotated as stateless (stateless is required for EJB logic) due to a [2 year old RestEasy bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-532).

1. Can anyone think of a solution to this issue?
2. Alternatively, is there a more typical solution that prepopulating these objects using a filter?

Kind thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done before is that I have a web application, "facade" if you want, to the EJBs. The JAX-RS layer is implemented in this application. A *servlet* filter intercepts the request to the JAX-RS resources and calls a *CDI* service that implements the "authenticate, lookup user code etc" logic. On success, the CDI service exports the current user object to CDI. This user object is `@Inject`'ed in the EJBs.

If CDI is an option for you (and I don't see why not in this setup), you could do the same (i.e. export the `User` to CDI) from your `SecurityFilter`, without having to create a web-app.

Additionally the dependency of the service layer (EJBs) to web-specific APIs (`HttpServletRequest`) is a bit creepy; I really think dependency injection of the actual `User` object is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, dependency injection is certainly the correct approach. Adding a RequestScoped store to share the user information was clean and simple and avoids polluting the EJB with the web specific APIs.